# Горизонтальный wow.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такой блок с горизонтальной прокруткой, animate.css и [wow.js](http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/):

```js
(function() {
  var MutationObserver, Util, WeakMap, getComputedStyle, getComputedStyleRX,
    bind = function(fn, me){ return function(){ return fn.apply(me, arguments); }; },
    indexOf = [].indexOf || function(item) { for (var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++) { if (i in this && this[i] === item) return i; } return -1; };

  Util = (function() {
    function Util() {}

    Util.prototype.extend = function(custom, defaults) {
      var key, value;
      for (key in defaults) {
        value = defaults[key];
        if (custom[key] == null) {
          custom[key] = value;
        }
      }
      return custom;
    };

    Util.prototype.isMobile = function(agent) {
      return /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(agent);
    };

    Util.prototype.createEvent = function(event, bubble, cancel, detail) {
      var customEvent;
      if (bubble == null) {
        bubble = false;
      }
      if (cancel == null) {
        cancel = false;
      }
      if (detail == null) {
        detail = null;
      }
      if (document.createEvent != null) {
        customEvent = document.createEvent('CustomEvent');
        customEvent.initCustomEvent(event, bubble, cancel, detail);
      } else if (document.createEventObject != null) {
        customEvent = document.createEventObject();
        customEvent.eventType = event;
      } else {
        customEvent.eventName = event;
      }
      return customEvent;
    };

    Util.prototype.emitEvent = function(elem, event) {
      if (elem.dispatchEvent != null) {
        return elem.dispatchEvent(event);
      } else if (event in (elem != null)) {
        return elem[event]();
      } else if (("on" + event) in (elem != null)) {
        return elem["on" + event]();
      }
    };

    Util.prototype.addEvent = function(elem, event, fn) {
      if (elem.addEventListener != null) {
        return elem.addEventListener(event, fn, false);
      } else if (elem.attachEvent != null) {
        return elem.attachEvent("on" + event, fn);
      } else {
        return elem[event] = fn;
      }
    };

    Util.prototype.removeEvent = function(elem, event, fn) {
      if (elem.removeEventListener != null) {
        return elem.removeEventListener(event, fn, false);
      } else if (elem.detachEvent != null) {
        return elem.detachEvent("on" + event, fn);
      } else {
        return delete elem[event];
      }
    };

    Util.prototype.innerWidth = function() {
      if ('innerWidth' in window) {
        return window.innerWidth;
      } else {
        return document.documentElement.clientWidth;
      }
    };

    return Util;

  })();

  WeakMap = this.WeakMap || this.MozWeakMap || (WeakMap = (function() {
    function WeakMap() {
      this.keys = [];
      this.values = [];
    }

    WeakMap.prototype.get = function(key) {
      var i, item, j, len, ref;
      ref = this.keys;
      for (i = j = 0, len = ref.length; j < len; i = ++j) {
        item = ref[i];
        if (item === key) {
          return this.values[i];
        }
      }
    };

    WeakMap.prototype.set = function(key, value) {
      var i, item, j, len, ref;
      ref = this.keys;
      for (i = j = 0, len = ref.length; j < len; i = ++j) {
        item = ref[i];
        if (item === key) {
          this.values[i] = value;
          return;
        }
      }
      this.keys.push(key);
      return this.values.push(value);
    };

    return WeakMap;

  })());

  MutationObserver = this.MutationObserver || this.WebkitMutationObserver || this.MozMutationObserver || (MutationObserver = (function() {
    function MutationObserver() {
      if (typeof console !== "undefined" && console !== null) {
        console.warn('MutationObserver is not supported by your browser.');
      }
      if (typeof console !== "undefined" && console !== null) {
        console.warn('WOW.js cannot detect dom mutations, please call .sync() after loading new content.');
      }
    }

    MutationObserver.notSupported = true;

    MutationObserver.prototype.observe = function() {};

    return MutationObserver;

  })());

  getComputedStyle = this.getComputedStyle || function(el, pseudo) {
    this.getPropertyValue = function(prop) {
      var ref;
      if (prop === 'float') {
        prop = 'styleFloat';
      }
      if (getComputedStyleRX.test(prop)) {
        prop.replace(getComputedStyleRX, function(_, _char) {
          return _char.toUpperCase();
        });
      }
      return ((ref = el.currentStyle) != null ? ref[prop] : void 0) || null;
    };
    return this;
  };

  getComputedStyleRX = /(\-([a-z]){1})/g;

  this.WOW = (function() {
    WOW.prototype.defaults = {
      boxClass: 'wow',
      animateClass: 'animated',
      offset: 0,
      mobile: true,
      live: true,
      callback: null
    };

    function WOW(options) {
      if (options == null) {
        options = {};
      }
      this.scrollCallback = bind(this.scrollCallback, this);
      this.scrollHandler = bind(this.scrollHandler, this);
      this.resetAnimation = bind(this.resetAnimation, this);
      this.start = bind(this.start, this);
      this.scrolled = true;
      this.config = this.util().extend(options, this.defaults);
      this.animationNameCache = new WeakMap();
      this.wowEvent = this.util().createEvent(this.config.boxClass);
    }

    WOW.prototype.init = function() {
      var ref;
      this.element = window.document.documentElement;
      if ((ref = document.readyState) === "interactive" || ref === "complete") {
        this.start();
      } else {
        this.util().addEvent(document, 'DOMContentLoaded', this.start);
      }
      return this.finished = [];
    };

    WOW.prototype.start = function() {
      var box, j, len, ref;
      this.stopped = false;
      this.boxes = (function() {
        var j, len, ref, results;
        ref = this.element.querySelectorAll("." + this.config.boxClass);
        results = [];
        for (j = 0, len = ref.length; j < len; j++) {
          box = ref[j];
          results.push(box);
        }
        return results;
      }).call(this);
      this.all = (function() {
        var j, len, ref, results;
        ref = this.boxes;
        results = [];
        for (j = 0, len = ref.length; j < len; j++) {
          box = ref[j];
          results.push(box);
        }
        return results;
      }).call(this);
      if (this.boxes.length) {
        if (this.disabled()) {
          this.resetStyle();
        } else {
          ref = this.boxes;
          for (j = 0, len = ref.length; j < len; j++) {
            box = ref[j];
            this.applyStyle(box, true);
          }
        }
      }
      if (!this.disabled()) {
        this.util().addEvent(window, 'scroll', this.scrollHandler);
        this.util().addEvent(window, 'resize', this.scrollHandler);
        this.interval = setInterval(this.scrollCallback, 50);
      }
      if (this.config.live) {
        return new MutationObserver((function(_this) {
          return function(records) {
            var k, len1, node, record, results;
            results = [];
            for (k = 0, len1 = records.length; k < len1; k++) {
              record = records[k];
              results.push((function() {
                var l, len2, ref1, results1;
                ref1 = record.addedNodes || [];
                results1 = [];
                for (l = 0, len2 = ref1.length; l < len2; l++) {
                  node = ref1[l];
                  results1.push(this.doSync(node));
                }
                return results1;
              }).call(_this));
            }
            return results;
          };
        })(this)).observe(document.body, {
          childList: true,
          subtree: true
        });
      }
    };

    WOW.prototype.stop = function() {
      this.stopped = true;
      this.util().removeEvent(window, 'scroll', this.scrollHandler);
      this.util().removeEvent(window, 'resize', this.scrollHandler);
      if (this.interval != null) {
        return clearInterval(this.interval);
      }
    };

    WOW.prototype.sync = function(element) {
      if (MutationObserver.notSupported) {
        return this.doSync(this.element);
      }
    };

    WOW.prototype.doSync = function(element) {
      var box, j, len, ref, results;
      if (element == null) {
        element = this.element;
      }
      if (element.nodeType !== 1) {
        return;
      }
      element = element.parentNode || element;
      ref = element.querySelectorAll("." + this.config.boxClass);
      results = [];
      for (j = 0, len = ref.length; j < len; j++) {
        box = ref[j];
        if (indexOf.call(this.all, box) < 0) {
          this.boxes.push(box);
          this.all.push(box);
          if (this.stopped || this.disabled()) {
            this.resetStyle();
          } else {
            this.applyStyle(box, true);
          }
          results.push(this.scrolled = true);
        } else {
          results.push(void 0);
        }
      }
      return results;
    };

    WOW.prototype.show = function(box) {
      this.applyStyle(box);
      box.className = box.className + " " + this.config.animateClass;
      if (this.config.callback != null) {
        this.config.callback(box);
      }
      this.util().emitEvent(box, this.wowEvent);
      this.util().addEvent(box, 'animationend', this.resetAnimation);
      this.util().addEvent(box, 'oanimationend', this.resetAnimation);
      this.util().addEvent(box, 'webkitAnimationEnd', this.resetAnimation);
      this.util().addEvent(box, 'MSAnimationEnd', this.resetAnimation);
      return box;
    };

    WOW.prototype.applyStyle = function(box, hidden) {
      var delay, duration, iteration;
      duration = box.getAttribute('data-wow-duration');
      delay = box.getAttribute('data-wow-delay');
      iteration = box.getAttribute('data-wow-iteration');
      return this.animate((function(_this) {
        return function() {
          return _this.customStyle(box, hidden, duration, delay, iteration);
        };
      })(this));
    };

    WOW.prototype.animate = (function() {
      if ('requestAnimationFrame' in window) {
        return function(callback) {
          return window.requestAnimationFrame(callback);
        };
      } else {
        return function(callback) {
          return callback();
        };
      }
    })();

    WOW.prototype.resetStyle = function() {
      var box, j, len, ref, results;
      ref = this.boxes;
      results = [];
      for (j = 0, len = ref.length; j < len; j++) {
        box = ref[j];
        results.push(box.style.visibility = 'visible');
      }
      return results;
    };

    WOW.prototype.resetAnimation = function(event) {
      var target;
      if (event.type.toLowerCase().indexOf('animationend') >= 0) {
        target = event.target || event.srcElement;
        return target.className = target.className.replace(this.config.animateClass, '').trim();
      }
    };

    WOW.prototype.customStyle = function(box, hidden, duration, delay, iteration) {
      if (hidden) {
        this.cacheAnimationName(box);
      }
      box.style.visibility = hidden ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
      if (duration) {
        this.vendorSet(box.style, {
          animationDuration: duration
        });
      }
      if (delay) {
        this.vendorSet(box.style, {
          animationDelay: delay
        });
      }
      if (iteration) {
        this.vendorSet(box.style, {
          animationIterationCount: iteration
        });
      }
      this.vendorSet(box.style, {
        animationName: hidden ? 'none' : this.cachedAnimationName(box)
      });
      return box;
    };

    WOW.prototype.vendors = ["moz", "webkit"];

    WOW.prototype.vendorSet = function(elem, properties) {
      var name, results, value, vendor;
      results = [];
      for (name in properties) {
        value = properties[name];
        elem["" + name] = value;
        results.push((function() {
          var j, len, ref, results1;
          ref = this.vendors;
          results1 = [];
          for (j = 0, len = ref.length; j < len; j++) {
            vendor = ref[j];
            results1.push(elem["" + vendor + (name.charAt(0).toUpperCase()) + (name.substr(1))] = value);
          }
          return results1;
        }).call(this));
      }
      return results;
    };

    WOW.prototype.vendorCSS = function(elem, property) {
      var j, len, ref, result, style, vendor;
      style = getComputedStyle(elem);
      result = style.getPropertyCSSValue(property);
      ref = this.vendors;
      for (j = 0, len = ref.length; j < len; j++) {
        vendor = ref[j];
        result = result || style.getPropertyCSSValue("-" + vendor + "-" + property);
      }
      return result;
    };

    WOW.prototype.animationName = function(box) {
      var animationName;
      try {
        animationName = this.vendorCSS(box, 'animation-name').cssText;
      } catch (_error) {
        animationName = getComputedStyle(box).getPropertyValue('animation-name');
      }
      if (animationName === 'none') {
        return '';
      } else {
        return animationName;
      }
    };

    WOW.prototype.cacheAnimationName = function(box) {
      return this.animationNameCache.set(box, this.animationName(box));
    };

    WOW.prototype.cachedAnimationName = function(box) {
      return this.animationNameCache.get(box);
    };

    WOW.prototype.scrollHandler = function() {
      return this.scrolled = true;
    };

    WOW.prototype.scrollCallback = function() {
      var box;
      if (this.scrolled) {
        this.scrolled = false;
        this.boxes = (function() {
          var j, len, ref, results;
          ref = this.boxes;
          results = [];
          for (j = 0, len = ref.length; j < len; j++) {
            box = ref[j];
            if (!(box)) {
              continue;
            }
            if (this.isVisible(box)) {
              this.show(box);
              continue;
            }
            results.push(box);
          }
          return results;
        }).call(this);
        if (!(this.boxes.length || this.config.live)) {
          return this.stop();
        }
      }
    };

    WOW.prototype.offsetLeft = function(element) {
      var top;
      while (element.offsetLeft === void 0) {
        element = element.parentNode;
      }
      top = element.offsetLeft;
      while (element = element.offsetParent) {
        top += element.offsetLeft;
      }
      return top;
    };

    WOW.prototype.isVisible = function(box) {
      var bottom, offset, top, viewBottom, viewTop;
      offset = box.getAttribute('data-wow-offset') || this.config.offset;
      viewTop = window.pageXOffset;
      viewBottom = viewTop + Math.min(this.element.clientWidth, this.util().innerWidth() ) - offset;
      top = this.offsetLeft(box);
      bottom = top + box.clientWidth;
      return top <= viewBottom && bottom >= viewTop;
    };

    WOW.prototype.util = function() {
      return this._util != null ? this._util : this._util = new Util();
    };

    WOW.prototype.disabled = function() {
      return !this.config.mobile && this.util().isMobile(navigator.userAgent);
    };

    return WOW;

  })();

}).call(this);


// ---------------------------


var wow = new WOW( {
  boxClass:     'wow',
  animateClass: 'animated',
  offset:       100
}
                 );

wow.init();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.wrap {
  width: 1500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.section {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px 50px;
}

h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" />
  
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="section">
    <h2>Section 1</h2>
    
    <p class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="100ms">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit labore omnis, eius assumenda vitae laborum nihil minus voluptas velit facilis.
    </p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="section">
    <h2>Section 2</h2>
    
    <p class="wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay="100ms">
      Lorem ipsum dolor.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit labore omnis, eius assumenda vitae laborum nihil minus voluptas velit facilis.
    </p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="section">
    <h2>Section 3</h2>
    
    <p class="wow bounceIn" data-wow-delay="100ms">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique, alias!
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit labore omnis, eius assumenda vitae laborum nihil minus voluptas velit facilis.
    </p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="section">
    <h2>Section 4</h2>
    
    <p class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="100ms">
      Lorem ipsum.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit labore omnis, eius assumenda vitae laborum nihil minus voluptas velit facilis.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Пытаюсь развернуть анимацию, влезла в код wow.js и немного изменила его.

Было:

```
WOW.prototype.offsetTop = function(element) {
      var top;
      while (element.offsetTop === void 0) {
        element = element.parentNode;
      }
      top = element.offsetTop;
      while (element = element.offsetParent) {
        top += element.offsetTop;
      }
      return top;
    };

    WOW.prototype.isVisible = function(box) {
      var bottom, offset, top, viewBottom, viewTop;
      offset = box.getAttribute('data-wow-offset') || this.config.offset;
      viewTop = window.pageYOffset;
      viewBottom = viewTop + Math.min(this.element.clientHeight, this.util().innerHeight()) - offset;
      top = this.offsetTop(box);
      bottom = top + box.clientHeight;
      return top <= viewBottom && bottom >= viewTop;
    };
```

Стало:

```
WOW.prototype.offsetLeft = function(element) {
      var top;
      while (element.offsetLeft === void 0) {
        element = element.parentNode;
      }
      top = element.offsetLeft;
      while (element = element.offsetParent) {
        top += element.offsetLeft;
      }
      return top;
    };

    WOW.prototype.isVisible = function(box) {
      var bottom, offset, top, viewBottom, viewTop;
      offset = box.getAttribute('data-wow-offset') || this.config.offset;
      viewTop = window.pageXOffset;
      viewBottom = viewTop + Math.min(this.element.clientWidth, this.util().innerWidth() ) - offset;
      top = this.offsetLeft(box);
      bottom = top + box.clientWidth;
      return top <= viewBottom && bottom >= viewTop;
    };
```

Но все так же, появляется лишь блок в поле видимости при загрузке, для следующих блоков анимация не срабатывает.

**Вопрос:** Почему не срабатывают изменения, как переправить скрипт, чтобы анимация работала и для горизонтального скролла?

Comment: Проблема заключается в том, что не срабатывает обработчик скролла при горизонтальной прокрутке. Решается комментированием `overflow-x: auto;` в стилях. Но почему он перестает срабатывать пока не понятно

Comment: @Grundy, мда (( причина решила бы проблему, наверное ...потому что если использовать кастомный скролл malihu и вот убираю там в стилях везде overflow-x - не помогает решить эту же проблему ... почему-то (

Comment: тут скорее проблема в том, что подписка идет на window.scroll, а он в данном случае не прокручивается, а прокручивается какой-нибудь элемент

Comment: @Grundy, https://jsbin.com/xagodut/edit?html,css,js,output если за стандартный ползунок тянуть (прокручивать) то срабатывает, хотя и дергается, а вот если просто скроллить - не работает. не совместимые плагины видимо))

Comment: не customScrollbar он ж все overflow hidden ставить и эмулирует скролл, а не нативный использует. иначе его никак не кастомизировать, поэтому с ним вообще не должно работать:)

Comment: @Grundy, ответ на этот вопрос - убрать `overflow-x: auto;`, спасибо!

Comment: напиши тогда ответ

Comment: @Grundy, так напиши) а я отмечу!

Comment: мне лень. а ответ дать надо :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Решение - убрать `overflow-x: auto;` у `body`:

```js
(function() {
  var MutationObserver, Util, WeakMap, getComputedStyle, getComputedStyleRX,
    bind = function(fn, me){ return function(){ return fn.apply(me, arguments); }; },
    indexOf = [].indexOf || function(item) { for (var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++) { if (i in this && this[i] === item) return i; } return -1; };

  Util = (function() {
    function Util() {}

    Util.prototype.extend = function(custom, defaults) {
      var key, value;
      for (key in defaults) {
        value = defaults[key];
        if (custom[key] == null) {
          custom[key] = value;
        }
      }
      return custom;
    };

    Util.prototype.isMobile = function(agent) {
      return /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(agent);
    };

    Util.prototype.createEvent = function(event, bubble, cancel, detail) {
      var customEvent;
      if (bubble == null) {
        bubble = false;
      }
      if (cancel == null) {
        cancel = false;
      }
      if (detail == null) {
        detail = null;
      }
      if (document.createEvent != null) {
        customEvent = document.createEvent('CustomEvent');
        customEvent.initCustomEvent(event, bubble, cancel, detail);
      } else if (document.createEventObject != null) {
        customEvent = document.createEventObject();
        customEvent.eventType = event;
      } else {
        customEvent.eventName = event;
      }
      return customEvent;
    };

    Util.prototype.emitEvent = function(elem, event) {
      if (elem.dispatchEvent != null) {
        return elem.dispatchEvent(event);
      } else if (event in (elem != null)) {
        return elem[event]();
      } else if (("on" + event) in (elem != null)) {
        return elem["on" + event]();
      }
    };

    Util.prototype.addEvent = function(elem, event, fn) {
      if (elem.addEventListener != null) {
        return elem.addEventListener(event, fn, false);
      } else if (elem.attachEvent != null) {
        return elem.attachEvent("on" + event, fn);
      } else {
        return elem[event] = fn;
      }
    };

    Util.prototype.removeEvent = function(elem, event, fn) {
      if (elem.removeEventListener != null) {
        return elem.removeEventListener(event, fn, false);
      } else if (elem.detachEvent != null) {
        return elem.detachEvent("on" + event, fn);
      } else {
        return delete elem[event];
      }
    };

    Util.prototype.innerWidth = function() {
      if ('innerWidth' in window) {
        return window.innerWidth;
      } else {
        return document.documentElement.clientWidth;
      }
    };

    return Util;

  })();

  WeakMap = this.WeakMap || this.MozWeakMap || (WeakMap = (function() {
    function WeakMap() {
      this.keys = [];
      this.values = [];
    }

    WeakMap.prototype.get = function(key) {
      var i, item, j, len, ref;
      ref = this.keys;
      for (i = j = 0, len = ref.length; j < len; i = ++j) {
        item = ref[i];
        if (item === key) {
          return this.values[i];
        }
      }
    };

    WeakMap.prototype.set = function(key, value) {
      var i, item, j, len, ref;
      ref = this.keys;
      for (i = j = 0, len = ref.length; j < len; i = ++j) {
        item = ref[i];
        if (item === key) {
          this.values[i] = value;
          return;
        }
      }
      this.keys.push(key);
      return this.values.push(value);
    };

    return WeakMap;

  })());

  MutationObserver = this.MutationObserver || this.WebkitMutationObserver || this.MozMutationObserver || (MutationObserver = (function() {
    function MutationObserver() {
      if (typeof console !== "undefined" && console !== null) {
        console.warn('MutationObserver is not supported by your browser.');
      }
      if (typeof console !== "undefined" && console !== null) {
        console.warn('WOW.js cannot detect dom mutations, please call .sync() after loading new content.');
      }
    }

    MutationObserver.notSupported = true;

    MutationObserver.prototype.observe = function() {};

    return MutationObserver;

  })());

  getComputedStyle = this.getComputedStyle || function(el, pseudo) {
    this.getPropertyValue = function(prop) {
      var ref;
      if (prop === 'float') {
        prop = 'styleFloat';
      }
      if (getComputedStyleRX.test(prop)) {
        prop.replace(getComputedStyleRX, function(_, _char) {
          return _char.toUpperCase();
        });
      }
      return ((ref = el.currentStyle) != null ? ref[prop] : void 0) || null;
    };
    return this;
  };

  getComputedStyleRX = /(\-([a-z]){1})/g;

  this.WOW = (function() {
    WOW.prototype.defaults = {
      boxClass: 'wow',
      animateClass: 'animated',
      offset: 0,
      mobile: true,
      live: true,
      callback: null
    };

    function WOW(options) {
      if (options == null) {
        options = {};
      }
      this.scrollCallback = bind(this.scrollCallback, this);
      this.scrollHandler = bind(this.scrollHandler, this);
      this.resetAnimation = bind(this.resetAnimation, this);
      this.start = bind(this.start, this);
      this.scrolled = true;
      this.config = this.util().extend(options, this.defaults);
      this.animationNameCache = new WeakMap();
      this.wowEvent = this.util().createEvent(this.config.boxClass);
    }

    WOW.prototype.init = function() {
      var ref;
      this.element = window.document.documentElement;
      if ((ref = document.readyState) === "interactive" || ref === "complete") {
        this.start();
      } else {
        this.util().addEvent(document, 'DOMContentLoaded', this.start);
      }
      return this.finished = [];
    };

    WOW.prototype.start = function() {
      var box, j, len, ref;
      this.stopped = false;
      this.boxes = (function() {
        var j, len, ref, results;
        ref = this.element.querySelectorAll("." + this.config.boxClass);
        results = [];
        for (j = 0, len = ref.length; j < len; j++) {
          box = ref[j];
          results.push(box);
        }
        return results;
      }).call(this);
      this.all = (function() {
        var j, len, ref, results;
        ref = this.boxes;
        results = [];
        for (j = 0, len = ref.length; j < len; j++) {
          box = ref[j];
          results.push(box);
        }
        return results;
      }).call(this);
      if (this.boxes.length) {
        if (this.disabled()) {
          this.resetStyle();
        } else {
          ref = this.boxes;
          for (j = 0, len = ref.length; j < len; j++) {
            box = ref[j];
            this.applyStyle(box, true);
          }
        }
      }
      if (!this.disabled()) {
        this.util().addEvent(window, 'scroll', this.scrollHandler);
        this.util().addEvent(window, 'resize', this.scrollHandler);
        this.interval = setInterval(this.scrollCallback, 50);
      }
      if (this.config.live) {
        return new MutationObserver((function(_this) {
          return function(records) {
            var k, len1, node, record, results;
            results = [];
            for (k = 0, len1 = records.length; k < len1; k++) {
              record = records[k];
              results.push((function() {
                var l, len2, ref1, results1;
                ref1 = record.addedNodes || [];
                results1 = [];
                for (l = 0, len2 = ref1.length; l < len2; l++) {
                  node = ref1[l];
                  results1.push(this.doSync(node));
                }
                return results1;
              }).call(_this));
            }
            return results;
          };
        })(this)).observe(document.body, {
          childList: true,
          subtree: true
        });
      }
    };

    WOW.prototype.stop = function() {
      this.stopped = true;
      this.util().removeEvent(window, 'scroll', this.scrollHandler);
      this.util().removeEvent(window, 'resize', this.scrollHandler);
      if (this.interval != null) {
        return clearInterval(this.interval);
      }
    };

    WOW.prototype.sync = function(element) {
      if (MutationObserver.notSupported) {
        return this.doSync(this.element);
      }
    };

    WOW.prototype.doSync = function(element) {
      var box, j, len, ref, results;
      if (element == null) {
        element = this.element;
      }
      if (element.nodeType !== 1) {
        return;
      }
      element = element.parentNode || element;
      ref = element.querySelectorAll("." + this.config.boxClass);
      results = [];
      for (j = 0, len = ref.length; j < len; j++) {
        box = ref[j];
        if (indexOf.call(this.all, box) < 0) {
          this.boxes.push(box);
          this.all.push(box);
          if (this.stopped || this.disabled()) {
            this.resetStyle();
          } else {
            this.applyStyle(box, true);
          }
          results.push(this.scrolled = true);
        } else {
          results.push(void 0);
        }
      }
      return results;
    };

    WOW.prototype.show = function(box) {
      this.applyStyle(box);
      box.className = box.className + " " + this.config.animateClass;
      if (this.config.callback != null) {
        this.config.callback(box);
      }
      this.util().emitEvent(box, this.wowEvent);
      this.util().addEvent(box, 'animationend', this.resetAnimation);
      this.util().addEvent(box, 'oanimationend', this.resetAnimation);
      this.util().addEvent(box, 'webkitAnimationEnd', this.resetAnimation);
      this.util().addEvent(box, 'MSAnimationEnd', this.resetAnimation);
      return box;
    };

    WOW.prototype.applyStyle = function(box, hidden) {
      var delay, duration, iteration;
      duration = box.getAttribute('data-wow-duration');
      delay = box.getAttribute('data-wow-delay');
      iteration = box.getAttribute('data-wow-iteration');
      return this.animate((function(_this) {
        return function() {
          return _this.customStyle(box, hidden, duration, delay, iteration);
        };
      })(this));
    };

    WOW.prototype.animate = (function() {
      if ('requestAnimationFrame' in window) {
        return function(callback) {
          return window.requestAnimationFrame(callback);
        };
      } else {
        return function(callback) {
          return callback();
        };
      }
    })();

    WOW.prototype.resetStyle = function() {
      var box, j, len, ref, results;
      ref = this.boxes;
      results = [];
      for (j = 0, len = ref.length; j < len; j++) {
        box = ref[j];
        results.push(box.style.visibility = 'visible');
      }
      return results;
    };

    WOW.prototype.resetAnimation = function(event) {
      var target;
      if (event.type.toLowerCase().indexOf('animationend') >= 0) {
        target = event.target || event.srcElement;
        return target.className = target.className.replace(this.config.animateClass, '').trim();
      }
    };

    WOW.prototype.customStyle = function(box, hidden, duration, delay, iteration) {
      if (hidden) {
        this.cacheAnimationName(box);
      }
      box.style.visibility = hidden ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
      if (duration) {
        this.vendorSet(box.style, {
          animationDuration: duration
        });
      }
      if (delay) {
        this.vendorSet(box.style, {
          animationDelay: delay
        });
      }
      if (iteration) {
        this.vendorSet(box.style, {
          animationIterationCount: iteration
        });
      }
      this.vendorSet(box.style, {
        animationName: hidden ? 'none' : this.cachedAnimationName(box)
      });
      return box;
    };

    WOW.prototype.vendors = ["moz", "webkit"];

    WOW.prototype.vendorSet = function(elem, properties) {
      var name, results, value, vendor;
      results = [];
      for (name in properties) {
        value = properties[name];
        elem["" + name] = value;
        results.push((function() {
          var j, len, ref, results1;
          ref = this.vendors;
          results1 = [];
          for (j = 0, len = ref.length; j < len; j++) {
            vendor = ref[j];
            results1.push(elem["" + vendor + (name.charAt(0).toUpperCase()) + (name.substr(1))] = value);
          }
          return results1;
        }).call(this));
      }
      return results;
    };

    WOW.prototype.vendorCSS = function(elem, property) {
      var j, len, ref, result, style, vendor;
      style = getComputedStyle(elem);
      result = style.getPropertyCSSValue(property);
      ref = this.vendors;
      for (j = 0, len = ref.length; j < len; j++) {
        vendor = ref[j];
        result = result || style.getPropertyCSSValue("-" + vendor + "-" + property);
      }
      return result;
    };

    WOW.prototype.animationName = function(box) {
      var animationName;
      try {
        animationName = this.vendorCSS(box, 'animation-name').cssText;
      } catch (_error) {
        animationName = getComputedStyle(box).getPropertyValue('animation-name');
      }
      if (animationName === 'none') {
        return '';
      } else {
        return animationName;
      }
    };

    WOW.prototype.cacheAnimationName = function(box) {
      return this.animationNameCache.set(box, this.animationName(box));
    };

    WOW.prototype.cachedAnimationName = function(box) {
      return this.animationNameCache.get(box);
    };

    WOW.prototype.scrollHandler = function() {
      return this.scrolled = true;
    };

    WOW.prototype.scrollCallback = function() {
      var box;
      if (this.scrolled) {
        this.scrolled = false;
        this.boxes = (function() {
          var j, len, ref, results;
          ref = this.boxes;
          results = [];
          for (j = 0, len = ref.length; j < len; j++) {
            box = ref[j];
            if (!(box)) {
              continue;
            }
            if (this.isVisible(box)) {
              this.show(box);
              continue;
            }
            results.push(box);
          }
          return results;
        }).call(this);
        if (!(this.boxes.length || this.config.live)) {
          return this.stop();
        }
      }
    };

    WOW.prototype.offsetLeft = function(element) {
      var top;
      while (element.offsetLeft === void 0) {
        element = element.parentNode;
      }
      top = element.offsetLeft;
      while (element = element.offsetParent) {
        top += element.offsetLeft;
      }
      return top;
    };

    WOW.prototype.isVisible = function(box) {
      var bottom, offset, top, viewBottom, viewTop;
      offset = box.getAttribute('data-wow-offset') || this.config.offset;
      viewTop = window.pageXOffset;
      viewBottom = viewTop + Math.min(this.element.clientWidth, this.util().innerWidth() ) - offset;
      top = this.offsetLeft(box);
      bottom = top + box.clientWidth;
      return top <= viewBottom && bottom >= viewTop;
    };

    WOW.prototype.util = function() {
      return this._util != null ? this._util : this._util = new Util();
    };

    WOW.prototype.disabled = function() {
      return !this.config.mobile && this.util().isMobile(navigator.userAgent);
    };

    return WOW;

  })();

}).call(this);


// ---------------------------


var wow = new WOW( {
  boxClass:     'wow',
  animateClass: 'animated',
  offset:       100
}
                 );

wow.init();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrap {
  width: 1500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.section {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px 50px;
}

h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" />
  
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="section">
    <h2>Section 1</h2>
    
    <p class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="100ms">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit labore omnis, eius assumenda vitae laborum nihil minus voluptas velit facilis.
    </p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="section">
    <h2>Section 2</h2>
    
    <p class="wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay="100ms">
      Lorem ipsum dolor.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit labore omnis, eius assumenda vitae laborum nihil minus voluptas velit facilis.
    </p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="section">
    <h2>Section 3</h2>
    
    <p class="wow bounceIn" data-wow-delay="100ms">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique, alias!
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit labore omnis, eius assumenda vitae laborum nihil minus voluptas velit facilis.
    </p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="section">
    <h2>Section 4</h2>
    
    <p class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="100ms">
      Lorem ipsum.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit labore omnis, eius assumenda vitae laborum nihil minus voluptas velit facilis.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Спасибо [@Grundy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186999/grundy)